# $6$ points on the unit circle

Tags: geometry, vectors, circles

I strongly believe that the following assertion is true:

> Suppose that $ v_1, \ldots, v_6 $ are $6$ points on $ S^1 \subset \mathbb{R}^2 $ satisfying $$ \sum_{i=1}^{6} \langle x,v_i \rangle ^2 =
>    3 $$ for any $ x \in S^1 $. Then for any $ x \in S^1 $, there exists $
>    v_i $ satisfying $$\langle x,v_i \rangle \geq \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} .$$

Obviously $ v_1, \ldots, v_6 $ seem to be the vertices of a regular
   hexagon. But I am not sure whether they must be. To prove the
   assertion, I think I have to either show that they must be the
   vertices of a regular hexagon, or, prove directly without assuming
   that they are. Can you help me with the proof? Thanks.

Comment: Is $S^1$ a circle cented at the origin with radius $1$?

Comment: yes!  $ S^1 = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x^2 + y^2 = 1 \} $

Comment: In the last inequality, should there be absolute value signs around the inner product?

Comment: I think there doesn't have to be absolute value sign. But if you can prove with absolute value sign, I also appreciate it. Or the squared version.

Comment: @syn3449 $S^r = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x^2 + y^2 = r^2 \}$? I am asking because I have never seen this notation before, is it standard?

Comment: @ovi $$S^d = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^{d + 1} \mid \|x\| = 1\}.$$

Comment: Actually $ S^d = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^{d+1} | \ldots \} $.

Comment: Ah thank you both @AlexFrancisco @syn3449!

Comment: Not sure it helps, but since all vectors are on the unit circle, then $<x,v_i>=\cos(\theta)$ where $\theta\in [0,\pi]$ is the (nonoriented) angle between $x$ and $v_i$. So $<x,v_i> \geqslant \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ means that $\theta \in [0,\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}]$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not true (sorry for answering my own question).

For example $ v_1, v_2, v_3 $ are the vertices of an equilateral triangle and set $ v_4 = v_1, v_5 = v_2, v_6 = v_3 $. Then for some $ x \in S^1 $, we have $ | \langle x, v_i \rangle | < \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} $ for every i.

Comment: Have you thought about the problem if we suppose that the six points are distinct?

Comment: Yes. Consider: $ v_1, v_2, v_3 $ are the vertices of an equilateral triangle and let $ v_4, v_5, v_6 $ be "slight" rotations of $ v_1, v_2, v_3 $.